# Как построить дендрограмму на javascript, используя библиотеку D3.js?

Tags: графика, javascript

Задача состоит в следующем - построить дендрограмму (по сути дерево) для визуализации иерархии объектов. В процессе поиска была обнаружена библиотека D3.js, которая может чуть менее, чем все, в том числе и выполнить требуемую задачу, однако какого-либо руководства или документации по ней на русском обнаружено не было. Возможно кто-то встречался с подобной задачей и имеет опыт ее решения. Буду благодарен за любую помощь и любую ссылку (желательно на русском). Заранее спасибо!

P.S. Собственно, как это должно выглядеть.

Пример дендрограммы:
[image: пример дендрограммы]

Comment: вам не хватает описания на английском ? может ещё и видеоуроки нужно  ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vdann/q2yVr/65/embedded/result/

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает ответ @vdann?

Comment: меня он более чем всем устраивает)отдал весь свой один балл репутации @vdann =))огромнейшее спасибо))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если человек спрашивает на русском, значит на английском ему не надо

Добавил в пример фильтрацию
http://jsfiddle.net/vdann/q2yVr/78/

Comment: ну и где у вас там описание на русском ? сэмплов то и демок на d3 куча.

Comment: Какое-то время назад хотел разобраться с d3js, но все как-то руки не доходили, а тут @proc_et_func спрашивает, вот этого примера и решил начать.
http://jsfiddle.net/vdann/q2yVr/107/embedded/ - добавил комментарии, может кто уточнит, и добавил вариант компоновки в полярной системе координат.